# Create scheduled task in scheduled task that runs power shell script

Tags: installshield, installshield-2012

I am struggling to create scheduled task that will execute power shell script.
I found only the documentation  that not help if you do this for the first time.
Can anyone point me to the right place.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what exactly is your problem.But i developed a scheduled task for install shield before a month, using the Automation Interface that Flexera provides.

[Install Shield 2012 Automation Interface](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield18helplib/IHelpAutoISWiProject.htm)

In the page above you will find how to open a current project or create a new one and after you manage all the project properties with the provided API through your program.

I found it easier to create a project from the GUI so i can use it as a Template after and just modify it from my program to fit my needs for every new project that i wanted to release.It was easier like this because i had only to modify the version and put new sources inside.

I hope i provided you with some new information,otherwise let me now if i misunderstood you and tell me what exactly is your problem so i can assist you better :)

Best Regards